# Give specific value to some attributes in uml

Tags: uml, class-diagram

On the classic aggregation example of car and wheel. A car has 4 wheels, wheel belongs to 1 car :

```
     1     4
Car <>------ Wheel
```

Now, wheel can be standard tyre, or snow tyre.

With the constraint of keeping one wheel class (no derived `snowWheel`, for example), how do I model that a car must have 2 snow tyres and 2 standard tyre?

Edit: edited to remove the "mandatory" boolean attribute

Comment: (1)  Is it acceptable to replace the aggregation by two separate aggregations, one for the standard tyre and one for the snow tyre?  (2)  Do you think it would be good to have a separate class `Tyre` associated with `Wheel`?

Comment: It can be two separate aggregation, but is that even authorized if they point to the same class? And I'd prefer avoiding to create new classes

Comment: Aggregation is allowed to point to the same class. It doesn't even matter, whether it is shared or composite aggregation. Bear in mind that aggregation is a statement about the instances. An instance can only be part of one _composite_ aggregation. However, a class can be related in multiple such aggregations (provided they have a multiplicity of 0..1). Shared aggregation (the one with the hollow diamond) doesn't have this restriction since it doesn't have semantics (at least in UML 2).

Comment: I have added the alternative with two composition relationships to my answer.

Comment: @sayanel, if you are satisfied with one of the answers, please mark it as accepted (green check mark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the class diagram, you could use a composite structure diagram for this purpose:

[image: compstruct]

If you want to stick to a regular class diagram, you could attach a note to the composition relationship: `two Wheels with standard tyres and two Wheels with snow tyres`.

Alternatively, you could replace the composition by two compositions, as follows:

[image: classdiagram]

Note that the multiplicities on the Car side are `0..1`, because a Wheel is either standard or snow, not both. This fact, and the fact that every Wheel belongs to a Car, must be specified in a constraint.

You can also specify the relationship with the Wheels as class attributes:

[image: classattributes]

You don't have composition anymore then, but the advantage is that you still have the wheels when your car is destroyed :-)

Comment: IIRC the picture is from the UML specs. If so, you should state that with ths figure number.

Comment: @qwerty_so,  I have replaced the figure from the UML specs with my own figure.

Comment: LOL that's an alternative. But simply using figures from the UML specs is fine - as long as you cite the source. I do that quite often.

Answer (score 3):

You have to attach a contraint to the association. That can simply be witten as an attached note with text in curly brackets like `{must have this and that sort of tyres}`. This could as well be written in OCL, but I'm not very firm in that and still think it's still more on an academic than practical level.

Of course you could extend your model with diffents tyre specializations and use generalization subsets. Depends on your needs.

Comment: With the constraint of having the information about the winter tyre in bool this is the only possibility I can think of. If we get rid of that limitation, there are some other options as well. Don't get me wrong, it is a comment for OP as the answer is spot on.

Comment: My constraint is more to have only one wheel class, and I assumed maybe wrongly that regular/snow would be an attribute of the class

Comment: You can make it an attribute (from an enumeration) and use that in your constraint. You are rather free in what you write in there.

Comment: @Ister Yes, thanks! The (currently) other answer has an attempt to model that. IIRC the picture is taken from the UML specs.